# Angular (Karma) - (isolated) Scope of Directive

Tags: angularjs, testing, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-runner

So, I started angular this weekend and I wrote myself a nice carousel app to begin with, good fun!

I wrote a neat directive for the carousel making it easy to use for whoever wants to install my carousel app. Unfortunatly I am getting stuck on retrieving the scope of the directive containing the functions I create there (I want to test them).

My karma.config.js contains the following related lines of code:

```
...
files: [
    // My templates
    'javascript/vendor/Directives/carousel/carousel.html',
]
...

...
preprocessors: {
    'javascript/vendor/Directives/carousel/carousel.html' : ['ng-html2js']
},
...

...
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    moduleName: 'myDirectives'
},
... 

...
// Which plugins to enable
plugins: [
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'
],
...
```

In my carouselDirective.js this is the relevant code:

```
angular.module('carouselApp').directive('carousel', function() {
return {
    restrict    : 'E',
    templateUrl : 'javascript/vendor/Directives/carousel/carousel.html',
    controller  : controller,
    scope       : {
        images : '=',
        theme  : '='
    }
};

function controller ($scope, $interval) {
...
    $scope.resetInterval = function () {
        $interval.cancel(carouselInterval);

        return carouselInterval = $interval(function() {
            $scope.nextImage();
        }, 5000);
    };
...
};
```

And finally in my controllerSpec.js

```
describe("Unit: Testing carouselApp - ", function() {
    var scope = undefined,
        ctrl  = undefined;

    beforeEach(module('carouselApp'));
    beforeEach(module('myDirectives'));

    beforeEach(
        inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $injector, $compile) { //injects the dependencies
            var $carouselService = $injector.get('carouselService'),
                carouselElement  = angular.element('<carousel images="images" theme="theme"></carousel>');

            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            ctrl  = $controller('carouselController', {
                $scope : scope,
                theme  : 'fantasy',
                images : $carouselService.getFantasyImages()
            });

            $compile(carouselElement)(scope);

            scope.$digest();

            // THIS HERE IS THE PROBLEM:
            // the first parameter in the log contains the scope I created from $rootScope and the isolateScope is simply undefined.
            // How can I get the scope from the directive containing the resetInterval function?
            console.log(carouselElement.scope(), carouselElement.isolateScope());
        })
    );
});
```

This is the situation, for those that skipped reading the code.. I added the problem I am encountering in the comments of the controllerSpec.js!

Any help is much appreciated. I have scoured google and stackoverflow.. I am not saying the answer to my problem is not there, but if it is I may need a bit more of a hand to understand whats going on :)

Regards,

A new angular enthusiast!

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, it turned out.. the code I had was fine. The instance of karma in my terminal seems to have bugged out somehow. Closing the terminal and opening a whole new one somehow solved the problem!

Partially happy it seems like I'm getting the hang of this, but that was a big chunk of my nights rest just for that! haha :)

Thanks for those that pondered upon the question!

Comment: Very interesting, I encountered the same thing. element.isolateScope was undefined, then I opened a new tab in iterm, and isolateScope is now defined.